# Python Pandas: How to optimally compare each value of a dictionary with all other values?

Tags: python, dictionary, pandas, comparison

I have a dictionary 'orgs_dict', and I would like to compare each value with all of the values, for that I put all of the values in a set and then did a comparison, if they are the same I add it to the 'final_hosts' dictionary:

```
orgs_dict = {'Ridgway School': 'ridgway','Ridgway Uni': 'ridgway', 'Aktieselskapet': 'aktieselskapet','Aktieselskapet_1': 'aktieselskapet', 'Chinese Education Association Ex': 'chinese association ex', 'Gestora de Infraestructuras de Telecomunicaciones': 'gestora infraestructuras telecomunicaciones','Aktieselskapet_5': 'aktieselskapet'}
```

here is my code:

```
set_neworgs=set()
for key in orgs_dict.keys():
    set_neworgs.add(orgs_dict[key])

final_hosts = defaultdict(list)
for i in set_neworgs:
    for k,v in orgs_dict.items():
        if i == v:
            final_hosts[i].append(k)
```

This works fine but when my 'orgs_dict'  is very huge it takes 3 hours to finish. I am wondering does any body know a more optional method?

Comment: So you want to filter your dict dependent on whether there are 2 or more duplicates? You sample dict shows no duplicates, do you care about the keys?

Comment: @EdChum I edited the sample dict. I would like to know the keys for which the values are the same.

Comment: Tip: `set_neworgs = set(orgs_dict.keys())`

Comment: @MrE thanks also a good tip. I am guessing the bottleneck is more on the comparison side. Do you have any tip for that also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can constuct a df using the keys as columns 'new_orgs', and the values as 'hosts' and then use `value_counts() > 1` as a boolean filter and then filter the hosts that are present in this series using `isin`:

```
In [150]:

orgs_dict = {'Ridgway School': 'ridgway','Ridgway Uni': 'ridgway', 'Aktieselskapet': 'aktieselskapet','Aktieselskapet_1': 'aktieselskapet', 'Chinese Education Association Ex': 'chinese association ex', 'Gestora de Infraestructuras de Telecomunicaciones': 'gestora infraestructuras telecomunicaciones','Aktieselskapet_5': 'aktieselskapet'}
df =pd.DataFrame({'new_orgs':list(orgs_dict.keys()), 'hosts':list(orgs_dict.values())})
df
Out[150]:
                                         hosts  \
0                               aktieselskapet   
1                                      ridgway   
2                               aktieselskapet   
3                                      ridgway   
4                       chinese association ex   
5  gestora infraestructuras telecomunicaciones   
6                               aktieselskapet   

                                            new_orgs  
0                                   Aktieselskapet_1  
1                                     Ridgway School  
2                                   Aktieselskapet_5  
3                                        Ridgway Uni  
4                   Chinese Education Association Ex  
5  Gestora de Infraestructuras de Telecomunicaciones  
6                                     Aktieselskapet  

In [157]:

df[df['hosts'].isin((df['hosts'].value_counts()[df['hosts'].value_counts()> 1].index))]
Out[157]:
            hosts          new_orgs
0  aktieselskapet  Aktieselskapet_1
1         ridgway    Ridgway School
2  aktieselskapet  Aktieselskapet_5
3         ridgway       Ridgway Uni
6  aktieselskapet    Aktieselskapet
```

An alternative is to `groupby` 'host` and then just count the number of 'new_orgs' and use this to filter:

```
In [167]:

df['host_count'] = df.groupby('hosts')['new_orgs'].transform('count')
df[df['host_count'] > 1]
Out[167]:
            hosts          new_orgs  host_count
0  aktieselskapet  Aktieselskapet_1           3
1         ridgway    Ridgway School           2
2  aktieselskapet  Aktieselskapet_5           3
3         ridgway       Ridgway Uni           2
6  aktieselskapet    Aktieselskapet           3
```

**timings**

On this small sample set I get

```
In [168]:

%%timeit
df['host_count'] = df.groupby('hosts')['new_orgs'].transform('count')
df[df['host_count'] > 1]
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.65 ms per loop

In [169]:

%timeit df[df['hosts'].isin((df['hosts'].value_counts()[df['hosts'].value_counts()> 1].index))]
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.49 ms per loop
```

So not much difference, your current method is quicker:

```
In [175]:

%%timeit
set_neworgs=set()
for key in orgs_dict.keys():
    set_neworgs.add(orgs_dict[key])
​
final_hosts = defaultdict(list)
for i in set_neworgs:
    for k,v in orgs_dict.items():
        if i == v:
            final_hosts[i].append(k) 
100000 loops, best of 3: 6.85 µs per loop
```

However, it won't scale well to your actual dataset size whilst the 2 methods above will

Comment: Thanks EdChum, a different perspective on the data, more pandas-wise. I just tried the first method and in some of the cases I still get 'hosts' with one value (whereas the condition is >1 ) why do think this is happening?

Comment: You'll have to post data so that I can reproduce it, does the groupby method work?

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake. They both work perfectly. Thanks

Comment: EdChum One extra question. what if instead of 'orgs_dict' of have a set of dicts just that, with different keys like this : final_dict[key]= orgs_dict. Can I put your code in a loop for all the keys in final_dict?

Comment: I'd either construct a df for each dict and then `concat` them all, or flatten all the dicts into a single dict and construct a df from that flattened dict

Comment: There is a [related post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5236296/how-to-convert-list-of-dict-to-dict) showing how to flatten a list of dicts into a single dict

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75830/discussion-between-userymy-and-edchum).

Comment: since at the end I want to compare the result of different keys, I'd rather not flatten them into one. But the constructing a dic and concatenating them all is not clear for me.

Comment: Something like `df_list=[] for d in final_dict: df = pd.DataFrame({'new_orgs':list(d.keys()), 'hosts':list(d.values())}) df_list.append(df)` then at the end of your code you could do `merged=pd.concat(df_list, ignore_index=True)`

Answer (score 1):

**Python 2.7+**: The keys for which the values are the same can be found with this dictionary comprehension:

```
{k: orgs_dict[k] for k in orgs_dict  if orgs_dict.values().count(orgs_dict[k])>1}
```

**Python 3.x**: wrap the `orgs_dict.values()` in a call to `list`:

```
{k: orgs_dict[k] for k in orgs_dict  if list(orgs_dict.values()).count(orgs_dict[k])>1}
```

Output:

```
{'Aktieselskapet_1': 'aktieselskapet', 'Ridgway School': 'ridgway', 'Aktieselskapet': 'aktieselskapet', 'Ridgway Uni': 'ridgway', 'Aktieselskapet_5': 'aktieselskapet'}
```

Another method:
In 2.7+ and 3.x make use of `Counter` from the `collections` module:

```
from collections import Counter
c = Counter(orgs_dict.values()) # count values
{k : orgs_dict[k] for k in orgs_dict.keys() if c[orgs_dict[k]]>1}
```

Comment: I see values, not keys here

Comment: @Vidhya GAttributeError: 'dict_values' object has no attribute 'count'. and I am looking both values and key for values that are the same

Comment: @Vidhya I am getting this error with your code AttributeError: 'dict_values' object has no attribute 'count'

Comment: I am not sure  why you got the Attribute error (i am using Python 2.7.6). I'll update so that you have the Keys.

Comment: Thanks. Because I am using Python 3.x

Comment: @UserYmY i've added another method that will work for Python3 (and 2.7+).

Comment: @VidhyaG thanks for your help, it is a bit less scalable to the other method posted but still faster than mine.