# Pull a specific value from a specific Dict in a List of Dict's

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of dict's...

```
categories = [{'summarycategory': {'amount':1233}},
             {'hhCategory': {}},
             {'information': {'mRoles': ['4456'],
                              'cRoles': None,
                              'emcRoles': ['spm/4456']}}]
```

I want to get value information.emcRoles. To do this, I do:

```
for x in categories:
    for key in x:
        if key == "information":
            print(x[key]["emcRoles"])
```

There must be a more pythonic way? 
Also, need it needs to be null safe.  So if, `"information"` is not there, I don't want a null pointer looking for emcRoles.

Comment: Is `emcRoles` always under `information`?

Comment: Is there always only *one* dictionary with `information` key? Or do you need to cater for multiple dictionaries / matches?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

don't *loop* on the keys, you're killing the use of the dict key lookup (plain loop is `O(n)`, dict lookup is `O(1)`

Instead, just check if key belongs, and go get it if it does.

```
for x in categories:
    if "information" in x:
        print(x["information"]["emcRoles"])
```

or use `dict.get` to save a dict key access:

```
for x in categories:
    d = x.get("information")
    if d is not None:   # "if d:" would work as well here
        print(d["emcRoles"])
```

to create a list of those infos instead, use a listcomp with a condition (again, listcomp makes it difficult to avoid the double dict key access):

```
[x["information"]["emcRoles"] for x in categories if "information" in x]
```

Comment: For the list option, I'd say it depends on what percentage of dictionaries contain "information". If it is a usual / *expected* key, then a `try` / `except` or `x.get(..., {}).get(..., None)` may be more appropriate. If it's not expected, then your method looks good.

Comment: yeah, also using `get` would save a dict access.

Answer (score 2):

A one-liner:

```
next(x for x in categories if 'information' in x)['information']['emcRoles']
```

Answer (score 1):

If `information` or `emcRoles` might be missing, you can either "ask for forgiveness", by wrapping it all in a `try..except`

```
try:
    for x in categories:
        if "information" in x:
            print(x["information"]["emcRoles"])
except:
    # handle gracefully ...
```

or you could use `get()` and provide fallback values as you see fit:

```
for x in categories:
    print(x.get("information", {}).get("emcRoles", "fallback_value"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what else you're doing with your categories list it might make sense to convert your list of dictionaries to new dictionary:

```
newdictionary=dict([(key,d[key]) for d in categories for key in d])
print(newdictionary['information']['emcRoles'])
```

See [how to convert list of dict to dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5236296/how-to-convert-list-of-dict-to-dict) for more.