# Convert list of dictionaries into dictionary in Postgres jsonb

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

I have an `actions_table` looking like:

```
profile_id | action_name | action_count
1          | action1     | 2
1          | action2     | 5
2          | action1     | 3
2          | action2     | 6
2          | action3     | 7
3          | action1     | 1
```

I would like to aggregate by profile_id and jsonify as:

```
profile_id | actions_count
1          | {"action1": 2, "action2": 5}
2          | {"action1": 3, "action2": 6, "action3": 7}
3          | {"action1": 1}
```

The closest I could get to is:

```
profile_id | actions_count
1          | [{"action1": 2}, {"action2": 5}]
2          | [{"action1": 3}, {"action2": 6}, {"action3": 7}]
3          | [{"action1": 1}]
```

By means of the query:

```
select profile_id,
jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_object(action_name, action_count)) as "actions_count"
from actions_table
group by profile_id
order by profile_id
```

How do I get to my desired result from here (convert list of dicts into dict), or how do I fix my original query?

CAVEATS

- I need a general answer, I might have > 10 action_names.
- I would like to avoid text replacement, e.g. `concat('{',replace(replace(replace(replace(jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_object(action_name, action_count)))::text, '[', ''), ']', ''), '{', '' ), '}', ''), '}')::jsonb`

Comment: Here is what I would do in Python, but need it in Postgres:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5236296/how-to-convert-list-of-dict-to-dict

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using `jsonb_object_agg()`

```
select profile_id, jsonb_object_agg(action_name, action_count)
from actions_table
group by profile_id;
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=04202cf7c9f09654cc06c3a5e2e25016)

Answer (score 0):

Ok so now that we have all informations, you can do it like that:

```
with p as (select distinct profile_id from actions_table)
select p.profile_id,json_object(array_agg(action_name),array_agg(action_count::varchar)) 
from p,actions_table
where p.profile_id = actions_table.profile_id
group by p.profile_id
```

Comment: I need a general and dynamical answer, I might have > 10 type of actions as keys. I know how to statically generate a dictionary.

Comment: First this query `json_agg(jsonb_build_object(key, value))` returns `[{"action1_count": 13}, {"action2_count": 39}]` and not `[{action1_count: 13}, {action2_count: 39}]`. In json keys are  enclosed by double quotes. if you want a correct answer, ask the good question. If your actions are retrieved from a table, you must give a description of your table and datas otherwise you will not have the answer.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the missing quotes.

Comment: OKKK, just brilliant. Sorry for posting an incomplete question initially. Thanks Philippe :)