# how to convert list of dict to dict when some keys repeated

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I have list of dictionaries, similar to this:

```
results=[{'year':2020,'id':'321abc','color':'blue'},
{'year':2020,'id':'412nbg','color':'brown'},
{'year':2021,'id':'klp54','color':'yellow'}...]
```

I want to organize it, to be one dictionary instead of list with dictionary, and also, to organize it so I have year as key, and then all the id and colors as values. I [saw this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5236296/how-to-convert-list-of-dict-to-dict) which has similar problem, however, they keys there were unique (names in the referenced post), while I have it repeating (years in my example).

So in the end maybe it will be nested dictionary , something like this:

```
results={ 2020:{id{},color{}},2020:{id{},color{},2022:{id:{},color:{}}
```

(when I have many ids and colors in each year)
How can I do this ?

Comment: make a dictionary that has a list of dictionaries. `{2020: [ {"id": "321abc", "color":"blue"}, {"id": "412nbg", "color":"brown"} ], 2021: [ {"id": "klp54", "color":"yellow"} ] }`

Comment: Also, what if you have exact duplicate dictionaries in your list? Surely you need to start by designing the data structure that you want, then you can work on the code to transpose the list of dicts into that structure.

Comment: @DavidBuck I don't understand your point, can you elaborate? just to give mroe information, I have tunique id, and they appear for every year.

Comment: My point is that you weren't explicit about your data (you mentioned that the example had unique names while yours were repeating), and you weren't explicit about exactly what you were trying to achieve. You have one answer already, which isn't what you seemed to be asking for, but unless you make your question clearer, people don't really know what you need to achieve.

Comment: @DavidBuck I have re-phrase it, let me know if now is more clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `itertools.groupby` and a few list and dictionary comprehensions, this is trivial. Remember that you need to sort first or `groupby` will not work the way you want. You will get repeated groups.

```
results = [{'year': 2020, 'id': '321abc', 'color': 'blue'},
           {'year': 2020, 'id': '412nbg', 'color': 'brown'},
           {'year': 2021, 'id': 'klp54', 'color': 'yellow'}]

from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

year = itemgetter('year')

r = sorted(results, key=year)
# [{'year': 2020, 'id': '321abc', 'color': 'blue'}, 
#  {'year': 2020, 'id': '412nbg', 'color': 'brown'}, 
#  {'year': 2021, 'id': 'klp54', 'color': 'yellow'}]

g = groupby(r, key=year)
# <itertools.groupby object at 0x7f9f2a232138>

{k: [{'id': x['id'], 'color': x['color']} for x in v] 
     for k, v in g}
# {2020: [{'id': '321abc', 'color': 'blue'}, 
#         {'id': '412nbg', 'color': 'brown'}], 
#  2021: [{'id': 'klp54', 'color': 'yellow'}]}
```