# Post data (dictionary list) with python requests

Tags: python, django, python-requests

I'd like to post my dictionary list below via python's http requests.

```
my_data=[
   {
     'kl':'ngt',
     'schemas':
       [
        {
         'date':'14-12-2022',
         'name':'kolo'
        }
      ],
   },

   {

    'kl':'mlk',
    'schemas':
       [
         {
           'date':'23-10-2022',
           'name':'maka'
       }
    ]
  }
 ]
```

trying to do

```
url='http://myapi.com/product
x=requests.post(url,json=my_data)
```

after execution it does not post the products on the database

Comment: Multiple things can happen here. Do you have an http response code or a stacktrace to share. There are not enough details with your current question.

Comment: status code is different from 200,
is in these condition used data=my_data instead of json=my_data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think when you want to send json payload in post request you should add headers argument:

```
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Accept':'application/json'}

r = requests.post(url = 'http://myapi.com/product', data = my_data, headers=headers)

response_result = r.text
```

then check response status code of the post request, If it isn't `200` then post request doesn't completed successfully.

Comment: the code is different from 200 , i will like to know using json=my_data is valid , if it is known that my_data is a dictionary list

Comment: @PathiaNanto check the documentation for making requests: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#make-a-request

Comment: Normally with json= you can pass a dict. Currently you pass a list, it might be a problem (did not double check on my side). What is your http status?

Comment: @Oghli I would like to turn my dictionary list into a dictionary like this, all_data={ {...},{...} } ?

Comment: @PathiaNanto see this post on stackoverflow:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5236296/how-to-convert-list-of-dict-to-dict